# Node.js/Express Password Protected Page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm new to node.js/express!

In my case I have a chat site and a chat admin site.
When I go in _____:3000/admin, it asks for a password in a form.
Now how would I check if the password is the correct password, not in the client's java-script?
I'm trying to stay away from php, because its too confusing...
How would I do that and then send a html file which can not be accessed by the user?

This is not like the other questions because I DON'T want/need 'usernames'

Comment: You'll need to expand more on what you have implemented so far.

Comment: I used https://github.com/socketio/socket.io (the chat example)
added app.use('/admin', express.static(__dirname + '/admin'));
and made the folder!
In that folder there is a file named index.html with a form

Comment: Put the relevant code in your question.  `express.static()` doesn't prompt for a password, so I have no idea why you are seeing that.

Comment: No I mean in the form in the admin/index.html asks for a password so you can log in as an admin, but how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Passport](https://gist.github.com/manjeshpv/84446e6aa5b3689e8b84) module for local authentication.Keep a database of users with hashed passwords, using bcrypt module.

Comment: I dont need 'usernames', I just want a password authentication

Comment: OK, then you can make the username constant and hidden from the user. So just keep a password input on the page, let the user input a password and in the backend provide a username in the code. So the constant username could be "Admin" and then get the password from the user.